# Changing font size and style in VectorDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, legending, ticks

I have this:

```
VectorDensityPlot[{x, -y}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

and want to:

1) Add a label to the column bar legend on the side
2) Change the font size and style to Latin Modern Roman (LaTeX).

I managed to increase the font size with FrameTicks, but not the style. There aren't many examples around with VectorDensityPlot... I found loads for plot alone, but most of them don't work on VectorDensityPlot...

Comment: You should be able to do a lot of this with the [`BaseStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BaseStyle.html) option, give that a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To format the plot legend you will have to go beyond `PlotLegends -> Automatic`. Here is an example of a formatted plot legend.

```
VectorDensityPlot[{x, -y}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
   BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLabel -> "Cooper Std", 
   LabelStyle -> {Bold, 16, FontFamily -> "Cooper Std"}]]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 3):

To extend [m_goldberg's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119536/52), the legend functions (`BarLegend`, `LineLegend`, `PointLegend`, and `SwatchLegend`) use the plot's `LabelStyle`, by default. So, you can set the `LabelStyle` for the entire plot, if you want uniformity, e.g.

```
VectorDensityPlot[{x, -y}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLabel -> "Cooper Std"], 
 LabelStyle -> {Bold, 16, FontFamily -> "Cooper Std"}]
```

[image]